# ROS Answers SE migration: touch screen?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there.  i'm working on a robot prototype that has a touch screen as a user interface.  i have a few questions.  i've done some research in the last few days but i couldn't find any reliable source of information.  i would love to get feedback from everyone who's done this before.

1. hardware:  what type of touch screen manufacturer & product would you recommend that works well with ros & ubuntu?  we're using an intel nuc i5 for our robot.
2. software:  how do you go about building beautiful touch UI with ros & ubuntu?  different from tablets (which already have well defined sdk and api like in android and ios), i'm not sure what are the equivelance in ros & ubuntu.
3. ros support:  are there any ros packages that support touch UI yet?

any feedback, comment, advice is much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190789/touch-screen?/) by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A common approach is to simply use a tablet as a programmable touch screen interacting with a ROS based robot using rosjava.

That gives you the nice touchscreen SDK/API/UI design guidelines which users are used to. And you don't need to constrain the hardware that runs on the rest of the machines.

There are a lot of computers out there which support touch screen displays. However always check for reviews about linux compatibility. If it's linux compatible you should be able to use it with ROS relatively easily.

The only ROS ui type packages I know of is ros_osc but that's probably not what you're looking for.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2